# Punctuation with wildcard search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a custom analyzer on field `authlast` that replaces punctuation with space. So when search with `saint-`, I am able to get results, but when I search with `saint-*` I get no results. Any idea why?

How does `query_string` analyze the string before submitting it for the search? If it does not analyze how does the term looks like when `query_string` submits the term to the ES index?

```
$"query": {
    {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "saint-*",
            "fields": ["authlast"],
            "default_operator": "AND"
        }
    }
}
window.jQuery.
```